# why can't I use jsx like variable in react native

Tags: react-native

maybe I want to create data like this.

```
let foo = <Text>test</Text>;
```

or

```
let bar = {
  one: <View><Text>test</Text></View>,
};
```

I get error when I use these variables in `return (<foo />);`, how should I do like above data structure :(

thanks for your time.

regards.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example provided you're returning a `<foo />` component, not the `foo` variable referencing the `<Text>` component. If `<Text>test</Text>` is assigned to `foo` you can `return foo`.

```
return (<Text>test</Text>);
```

is the same as:

```
let foo = <Text>test</Text>;
return foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.

But you could build your component this way:

```
let foo = () => {
  return (
    <Text>test</Text>
  );
};
```

And then use it in another one in the render function as `<foo />`